# How to migrate SSAS and SSRS from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, migration, ssrs, ssas

We are upgrading our SQL Server 2008R2 to 2012 and separate the SQL Server engine from SSAS and SSRS. We want put on Server 1 the engine and on Server 2 SSAS and SSRS.

I did the side-by-side migration for the database. Now the SQL Server Engine and databases are on the SQL Server 2012(server 1).  On the older server we have SSAS and SSRS we want to migrate to new SQL Server 2012 server by itself.

**My Question is:**

> How to move the SSAS and SSRS from SQL Server 2008R2 to the new SQL
>   Server 2012(Server 2) ?

Comment: Is there anything in SSAS that only exists in SSAS? Just re-deploy your solutions and process the cubes on the new instance? Are you in native or sharepoint mode for SSRS?

Comment: @Dave The cubes need to be in SSAS and SSRS is in native.  I have never moved SSAS and SSRS to different server. can you direct me to some articles or document helps me to understand how to deploy .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have data in your SSAS cubes that no longer exists in your source (if this is the case correct that going forward!) then you can simply install a new instance of SSAS then deploy and process your SSAS solutions from SSDT (the 2012+ replacement for BIDS).

For SSRS if you have a basic install you can do the same thing - simply install the new server and deploy your reports. If you have a lot of reports, folders, security setup, schedules etc. then you should migrate.

Here are the MSDN Documents outlining the [steps to migrate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143724%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and the [considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143747%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#bkmk_migration_considerations) prior to doing so.